# Prove that the normalizers of Sylow subgroups have the same structure

Tags: group-theory

In relation to an earlier post I made,
[Prove there is no element of order 6 in a simple group of order 168](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71768/prove-there-is-no-element-of-order-6-in-a-simple-group-of-order-168)

The answer provided relies on this statement
"Therefore the normalizer of any Sylow 3-subgroup would have to be cyclic of order 6, and an element of order 6 belongs to exactly one such normalizer"

How does one prove that if one normalizer is cyclic, then they all must be cyclic? I accepted it as obvious at first, but then when I tried to prove it I found myself stuck and unable to show that this must be the case.

Comment: Sylow subgroups are conjugate, so their normalizers will also be conjugate; isn't it?

Comment: One meta way to do this is to ask "Did he use anything about which particular Sylow 3-subgroup it was?"  If not, then he not only showed a particular normalizer was cyclic, he proved a theorem about normalizes of Sylow 3-subgroups in that group: they are cyclic.  Whenever you see a conclusion, it is a good idea to make a quick note of what the hypotheses of that conclusion are.  That quick note is a (possibly useless, but possibly awesome) theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma.** Let $H<G$ and $g\in G$. Then $N_G(H^g) = (N_G(H))^{g}$.

*Proof.* If $x\in N_G(H^g)$, then for every $h\in H$ we have $x(ghg^{-1})x^{-1}\in H^g$; hence for each $h\in H$ there exists $h'\in H$ such that $xghg^{-1}x^{-1} = gh'g^{-1}$. Thus, $(g^{-1}xg)h(g^{-1}xg) = h'\in H$. That is, $g^{-1}xg\in N_G(H)$, so $x\in gN_G(H)g^{-1}$.

Thus, $N_G(H^g)\subseteq (N_G(H))^g$.

For the converse inclusion, by the same argument we have
$$(N_G(H))^g = \Bigl( N_G\bigl( (H^g)^{g^{-1}}\bigr)\Bigr)^g \subseteq \Bigl(\bigl(N_G(H^g)\bigr)^{g^{-1}}\Bigr)^g = N_G(H^g),$$
proving equality. $\Box$

Answer (score 2):

Two Sylow subgroups are conjugate. An element which conjugates them also conjugates their normalizers.