# Question on Hall's theorem for solvable groups

Tags: finite-groups, solvable-groups

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group with $|G|=p_{1}^{\alpha _{1}}\cdot \cdot\cdot p_{r}^{\alpha _{r}}$ such that $p_{1}$,..., $p_{r}$ are distinct primes. By Hall's theorem, we have:
If the number of  Sylow $p_{i}$-subgroups is $q_{1}^{\beta
_{1}}\cdot \cdot \cdot q_{s}^{\beta _{s}}$, then for all $i\in \{1,2,...,s\}$
, $q_{i}^{\beta _{i}}\equiv 1$ (mod $p_{i}$).

My question: Is the converse true? That is, if for every $p_{i}$ the number of Sylow $p_{i}$-subgroups is $q_{1}^{\beta_{1}}\cdot \cdot \cdot q_{s}^{\beta _{s}}$, and for all $i\in \{1,2,...,s\}$
, $q_{i}^{\beta _{i}}\equiv 1$ (mod $p_{i}$), then $G$ is solvable?

I have checked it for all the small nonsolvable groups and many others. I discovered that except for $PSL(2,7)$ and groups that have $PSL(2,7)$ as the composition factor, the rest do not have this property.

We must first answer the following question:

For a simple group $S\neq PSL(2,7)$ why there exists prime $p$ such that
if the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S$ is $q_{1}^{\beta _{1}}q_{2}^{\beta_{2}}\cdot \cdot \cdot q_{t}^{\beta _{t}}$, then at least for some $1\leq i\leq t$, $q_{i}^{\beta _{i}}\ncong 1$ (mod $p$).

Can anyone help in solving the above question?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simple group of order $168$. It has $8=2^3$ Sylow $7$-subgroups, $28=2^2\cdot7^1$ Sylow $3$-subgroups, and $21=3^1\cdot7^1$ Sylow $2$-subgroups. But it isn't solvable.

Comment: One starting point for the properties of this group is [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71768/11619). I would prefer another link as there isn't much there. Alas, [GroupProps](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group:PSL(3,2)) does not list Sylow data :-(

Comment: I think there is no other group except this one.

Comment: @AR Please add your own thoughts into the question body. While a natural question (upon learning about Hall's theorem - something I did not know!), some reviewers may think it is a bit lacking in context [check out the abridged guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619). Also include the results of your own (re)search. Makes the question that much more interesting!

Comment: I have checked it for all the small nonsolvable groups and many others. I discovered that except for PSL(2,7), the rest do not have this property.